# Skip null column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which contains 13 columns (ID, name, image, day1-10). The problem is: Most of the times I will have null columns. I was wondering how I could make so that my mysql query would get only the non-null columns, if that is even possible.

What I mean is, there won't always be day2-10 sometimes only day1 will be set and I would only want this value from this row. Is it possible? I tried googling it but didn't find anything that helped, I could only find ways to skip the entire row altogether

I would have to use PHP to fetch the results from this query.

I tried different queries but none of them worked

Comment: NORMALIZE your data

Comment: What's wrong with getting the whole row and just parsing your results with PHP? The only way that you can skip a column is if you state specific columns in your SELECT statement (instead of SELECT *).  But if you have values in day1 sometimes, and other time day1 is null then you will need to pull all those rows and just parse with PHP.

Comment: What do you want to do with the data once you get it from mysql?  The logic to not display the null values will be in your php code, not in the sql.

Comment: simple answer is yo need relation 1 to many for the days and then you can do left join and filter only NON-NULL values

Comment: What do you mean _only get non-null columns_? Are you having difficulty with filtering i.e., choosing the correct rows with your WHERE clause or are you having problems with the structure of the result set i.e., the SELECT clause. What are some of your failed SQL statements? Maybe you should share some sample data and which data should be returned and what the final result set should be.

Comment: As Strawberry mentioned, you should [**normalize**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data. You shouldn't have columns like `day1-10`. Instead, you should have one table for the first set of data (ID, name, image), and then another table for just the days, each of which relates back to a specific ID in the first table.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
Table Main

ID | name | image | day1 | day2 | day3 ...
-------------------------------------------
1  | Foo  | img1  | 7    | NULL | NULL
2  | Bar  | img2  | 9    | 13   | 14
```

You should normalize your data into two tables like this:

```
Table Main

ID | name | image 
------------------
1  | Foo  | img1
2  | Bar  | img2


Table Days

ID  | MainID | Day
------------------
100 | 1      | 7
101 | 2      | 9
102 | 2      | 13
103 | 2      | 14
```

Then, you will use a [JOIN](http://phpweby.com/tutorials/mysql/32) to select all of the days that apply to whichever element from the Main table you're interested in.

An additional benefit here is that you're no longer constrained to just 10 days.

Comment: You are a genius! Thank you very much. That solves all my issues